# How to set a metric condition in Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

My Azure SQL Managed Instance is showing the storage utilization chart as follows:

[image]

And the `Average Storage used metric` is showing as follows:

[image]

**Goal**: set a condition for the metric `Storage Space used` so that when the average space used exceeds 52k, I get an alert. Currently, average storage used is showing 51.74k as depicted in the image 2 below)

**Question**: what threshold value should I set in the Alert Rule, to achieve the above goal?

**Ref**: [Create alerts for Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/alerts-create?view=azuresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please configure in the Alert panel as shown below for a threshold limit of 52k.

Select Unit as "k" and Threshold value as 52

[image]